# I wanna make my text Responsive in CSS but I got Problem

Tags: html, css

I'm using media queries in my codes. I added breakpoint for my header and it worked very well but It doesn't work on my original text.
I thought that I can fix it by changing "pre" tag to "p" but It messed up and destroyed all of spacing on my text
so what do i do?
In my HTML : (main-title is a class of heading and original text is a class for "pre" tag)

In my CSS: my media queries. I tired to do on 768px screen first but it didn't work. same as other resolutions

```css
    /* Navbar starts ===============================================================================*/
    body{
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .container{
        width: 100%;
        height:78px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .logo{
        position: absolute;
        padding:0.6%;
        padding-top: 0.2%;
        
    }
    .nav-list{  
        font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        top: 1%;
        display: flex;
        padding:1.0%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .nav-list a{
        margin: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #80e560;
        transition: color 400ms ease-in-out;
    }
    .nav-list a:hover{
        color: #a8fbfc;
    }
    .nav-list ul{
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .hamburger{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    -moz-transform-origin: 20px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 20px;
    -o-transform-origin: 20px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 20px;
    transform-origin: 20px;
    transition: width 800ms ease-in-out;
    transition: height 800ms ease-in-out;
    
    }
    .hamburger div{
        width: 20px;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #80e560;
        margin: 3px;
        margin-left: 50%;
        transition: transform 210ms ease-in-out;
    }
    .sidemenu{
       position: absolute;
       right: 0px;
       width: 40%;
       height: 100%;
       width: 20%;
       background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
       transform:translateX(100%);
       transition:transform 500ms;
       z-index: 1;
       
    }
    .side-items{
        height:80%;
        justify-content:space-between;
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
        align-items : space-between;
    }
    .side-item{
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .side-item a{
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: color 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
    .side-item a:hover{color:#80e560;}
    @media screen and (max-width:1500px){
        .logo{padding-top: 0.3%;}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:768px){
        .nav-item{
            display: none;
        }
        .hamburger{
            display:inline;
            bottom: 12px;
            right: 35px;
        }
        .side-items{
            right: 20%;
        }
        .nav-list{
            padding: 40px;
        }
        .container{
            height: 89px;
        }
        .logo{padding-top: 2%;}
    .main-title{font-size: 3vw;}
    .Original-text{font-size: 3vw;}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:568px){
        .hamburger{
            right: 50%;
        }
        .side-items{
            right: 20%;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        .container{
            height: 89px;
        }
        .main-title{
            font-size: 4vw;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:280px)
    {     
         .side-items{
             right: 9%;
         }
         .hamburger{
             right: 6%;
         }
    }
    
    /* Navbar Ends ========================================================================*/
    .mid-section{
    background-image: url(/img/background.jpg);
    background-position:center; 
    background-size:cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 100vh;
    }
    @keyframes colorchange{
        0% { 
            color: rgb(216, 200, 86);
        }
        45% {
            color: rgb(231, 103, 71);
        }
        50% {
            color: rgb(198, 228, 73);
        }
        65% {
            color: rgb(179, 228, 73);
        }
        73%{
            color: rgb(70, 232, 155);
        }
        85%{
            color: rgb(70, 232, 211);
        }
        100%{
            color: rgb(69, 233, 224);
        }
    }
    .main-title{
    
        text-align: left;
        padding: 45px;
        color: rgb(234, 226, 164);
        animation-name:colorchange;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-duration: 7s;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .Original-text{
        font-size: 1.8vw;
        font-family: 'Sansita Swashed', cursive;
        padding-top: 0;
        color: gold;
       
    }
```

```html
    <!--Navbar Starts ====================================== -->
        <header>     
            <div class="container">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="logo"><img src="/img/logo.png"></div>
                        <div class="nav-list">
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
                            <div class="hamburger" onclick="clk()" id="burger">
                                <div id="line1"></div>
                                <div id="line2"></div>
                                <div id="line3"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
               </div>
               <div class="sidemenu" id="sdmenu">
                <div class="side-items">
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <script src="/func.js"></script>
    <!--Navbar End===========================================-->
    <div class="mid-section">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <h1 class="main-title">Welcome to the Land of Electronics</h1>
        <pre class="Original-text">
          This Land Will Show the Future! get any Electronics You need
          from us!
          eveything is ready for you. direct from manufacture
          Original components. with 2 years guarantee
          so lets go and and explore or world 
        </pre>
    </div>
```

Comment: vw? ever try using px/em/rem?

Comment: @Kenny No I didn't because in youtube I saw that most of guys uses this method to make text responsive

Comment: Most of "the guys on YouTube" are not experts :) and some people can favour the "next big thing" such as `vw` units and flexbox whether it is appropriate or not. You should really find a reputable resource to learn from :) @Kenny has a point - don't automatically jump to `vw` - other units can often be more appropriate. A huge number of questions here on SO are because people are making things way to complicated by using `vw` because they learned it from tutorials that are really not giving out the best advice.

Comment: @Kenny I tried right now but doesn't work

Comment: As for your question here, what exactly is the specific problem is that you are having?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I wanna change my font size in responsive mode using media queries but it doesn't work

Comment: then pls try to re-position your css code. put those media queries below the block of font-size 1.8vw, seems that this block of code is overriding

Comment: If thats all you need to do, I suggest you look at how to create a [MRE] that includes only the relevant code to the question - including lots of code that we have to go through to find the problem might be putting users off helping. Help us to help you and make it easier for us to find the problem :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten but you didn't even read my codes. I added media queries

Comment: @FluffyKitten read the sections that has "@media and screen"

Comment: I didn't say your code doesn't include the code we need, I said there is *way* too much extra code that we *don't*  need!  Please see [ask] - you should include a **[MRE]** with *only* the relevant code about the problem, The code for `head` and  `nav` are totally superfluous to the question, for example. To get help on SO, it is always better to follow the guidelines and include only the minimum code

Comment: @FluffyKitten OK I will do Thanks for advice. but can you read that for now and help me? next time I will be careful

Comment: @SMAKSS has already given you an answer that looks pretty good to me, I don't think there is anything I can add to improve on it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, using `vw` over standard `font-size` [units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) is up to you, but I really discourage you from using it in your projects because it will change the size of your element whenever the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts) width changes and depend on which box and element are you working on and how's your HTML markup structure is, it's gonna be act very differently in different situations.

But the actual problem here is with the order of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for your styles, due to this fact whatever comes last will overwrite the first so your queries won't work as expected. To get them to work *(In this particular case)* you can move all of them to the bottom of your styles.

```css
/* Navbar starts ===============================================================================*/

body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 78px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0.6%;
  padding-top: 0.2%;
}

.nav-list {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 1%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1.0%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-list a {
  margin: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #80e560;
  transition: color 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: #a8fbfc;
}

.nav-list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  -moz-transform-origin: 20px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 20px;
  -o-transform-origin: 20px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 20px;
  transform-origin: 20px;
  transition: width 800ms ease-in-out;
  transition: height 800ms ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #80e560;
  margin: 3px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transition: transform 210ms ease-in-out;
}

.sidemenu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 500ms;
  z-index: 1;
}

.side-items {
  height: 80%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  align-items: space-between;
}

.side-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.side-item a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.side-item a:hover {
  color: #80e560;
}



/* Navbar Ends ========================================================================*/

.mid-section {
  background-image: url(/img/background.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes colorchange {
  0% {
    color: rgb(216, 200, 86);
  }
  45% {
    color: rgb(231, 103, 71);
  }
  50% {
    color: rgb(198, 228, 73);
  }
  65% {
    color: rgb(179, 228, 73);
  }
  73% {
    color: rgb(70, 232, 155);
  }
  85% {
    color: rgb(70, 232, 211);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgb(69, 233, 224);
  }
}

.main-title {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 45px;
  color: rgb(234, 226, 164);
  animation-name: colorchange;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.Original-text {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  font-family: 'Sansita Swashed', cursive;
  padding-top: 0;
  color: gold;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1500px) {
  .logo {
    padding-top: 0.3%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .nav-item {
    display: none;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: inline;
    bottom: 12px;
    right: 35px;
  }
  .side-items {
    right: 20%;
  }
  .nav-list {
    padding: 40px;
  }
  .container {
    height: 89px;
  }
  .logo {
    padding-top: 2%;
  }
  .main-title {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
  .Original-text {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:568px) {
  .hamburger {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .side-items {
    right: 20%;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .container {
    height: 89px;
  }
  .main-title {
    font-size: 4vw;
    padding: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:280px) {
  .side-items {
    right: 9%;
  }
  .hamburger {
    right: 6%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>ElectroLand</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Navbar Starts ====================================== -->
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <div class="logo"><img src="/img/logo.png"></div>
        <div class="nav-list">
          <ul class="nav-item">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav-item">
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav-item">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="hamburger" onclick="clk()" id="burger">
            <div id="line1"></div>
            <div id="line2"></div>
            <div id="line3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="sidemenu" id="sdmenu">
      <div class="side-items">
        <ul class="side-item">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-item">
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-item">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="/func.js"></script>
  <!--Navbar End===========================================-->
  <div class="mid-section">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <h1 class="main-title">Welcome to the Land of Electronics</h1>
    <pre class="Original-text">
      This Land Will Show the Future! get any Electronics You need
      from us!
      eveything is ready for you. direct from manufacture
      Original components. with 2 years guarantee
      so lets go and and explore or world 
    </pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### Update

Well, since there were some complaints about why we should put redundant code into the answer, I just break it down to just the necessary part of code, which is too short and more readable.

```css
.main-title {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 45px;
  color: rgb(234, 226, 164);
  animation-name: colorchange;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.Original-text {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  font-family: 'Sansita Swashed', cursive;
  padding-top: 0;
  color: gold;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .main-title {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
  .Original-text {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:568px) {
  .main-title {
    font-size: 4vw;
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 class="main-title">Welcome to the Land of Electronics</h1>
<pre class="Original-text">
      This Land Will Show the Future! get any Electronics You need
      from us!
      eveything is ready for you. direct from manufacture
      Original components. with 2 years guarantee
      so lets go and and explore or world 
</pre>
```

Comment: You shouldn't copy this very redundant `nav`. `ul` isn't necessary, and using `ul` as a single item of a list is...  very you-tube-ish :) (didn't vote - its not a part of question)

Comment: @blackblue What is your suggest ? How can I make it  better ? instead of nav and ul and other stuffs

Comment: @blackblue Yes, there are so many down-sides for this code, but the point of the answer is to solving the OP question and optimizing the code was not part of it. So I preferred to leave the code as it is.

Comment: @HaythamKenway my suggest is that experienced coder should not put poor html even if it is not a part of question, because everything matters. And my not-vote is information for SMAKSS - his answer is good, follow it without any worries. If you want better html - well all is about the 'other stuffs', not a tragedy - I have high expectations

Comment: @blackblue Well, sometimes good complaints will make better answers. So I just made up my mind and decide to put only what is necessary.